# Как в js обрезать 5 символов?

Tags: javascript

Переменная из php передает "8187 \r\n". 
Как в js обрезать -  пробел\r\n, чтобы было "8187"; ?

```
var port4 = "148.251.68.37";
var port5 = "8187 \r\n";
```

Comment: Это не 5 символов, это 3 символа, ибо экранирование

Answer (score 3):

```js
console.log("[" + "8187 \r\n".trim() + "]");
```

Comment: Пробую так: `var port5 = <?php echo json_encode($chunks2[2]); ?>;
console.log("port5".trim());` Не идет...

Comment: `console.log(port5.trim());`

Comment: и возможно: `var port5 = '<?php echo json_encode($chunks2[2]); ?>';`

Comment: port5 выводит 8187 из txt файла. Если 8187 идет с пробелом или с пробелами (8187пробел) или (8187пробелпробел), то обрезать не получается. Вручную в  txt файле убираю пробел - работает. Все перепробовал, что предложили - не работает.

Answer (score 3):

А не логичнее прямо в PHP обрезать лишнее?

```
var port5 = <?php echo trim(json_encode($chunks2[2])); ?>;
console.log(port5);
```

Более того, если ваша цель в итоге получить число, то имеет смысл явно привести к целочисленному типу:

```
var port5 = <?php echo intval(json_encode($chunks2[2])); ?>;
console.log(port5);
```

Или, если вы во что бы то ни стало хотите манипулировать переменной на фронтэнде, то привести к целому её можно так:

```
var port5 = parseInt("<?php echo json_encode($chunks2[2])); ?>");
console.log(port5);
```

Answer (score 2):

В `javascript` есть функция для обрезания строки `substr`,
Пример использования:

```js
var str = '8187 \r\n';
console.log(str.substr(0,4));
```

Подробнее об этом можете смотреть [тут](https://javascript.ru/string/substr).